Why turtle is not positioning the components in their right positions in first iteration
I am using Pyscripter ide but also used in vscode same output problem.
I was expecting this from start (i.e. 1st iteration)

but instead it's coming like this

This Python script uses the Turtle module to simulate a traffic light. Here's a breakdown of how it works:

Drawing Functions: There are several functions defined to draw different elements of the traffic light scene, such as the sky, clouds, road, grass, traffic light pole, and text.

draw_sky(x, y): Draws a blue sky rectangle.

draw_cloud(x, y): Draws a cloud at the specified position.

draw_lawn(x, y): Draws a green lawn.

draw_road(x, y): Draws a black road.

draw_road_lines(x, y): Draws white lines on the road to simulate road markings.

draw_pole(x, y): Draws a gray pole for the traffic light.

draw_box(x, y): Draws a black box for the traffic light.

draw_text(x, y, message): Writes text at the specified position.

draw_traffic_light(x, y, active_light): Draws the traffic light itself. It calls the other drawing functions to compose the scene.

simulate_traffic_light(): This function continuously cycles through the traffic light colors (red, yellow, green) with a 2-second delay between each change.

close_window(): Closes the Turtle graphics window.

Setup and Mainloop: Sets up the Turtle window with a size of 600x760 pixels, sets the title and background color, hides the turtle cursor, sets the speed to 0 (fastest), listens for the 'c' key to close the window, and starts the traffic light simulation.

Main Execution: Calls the mainloop() function of the Turtle module, which keeps the window open and responsive to events.


This script demonstrates how to use the Turtle module to create simple animations and drawings in Python.
Here's the code
import turtle
import time

def draw_filled_circle(color, radius):
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.fillcolor(color)
turtle.circle(radius)
turtle.end_fill()

def draw_sky(x, y):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x , y)
turtle.goto(x + 300, y - 10)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("sky blue")
turtle.begin_fill()
for \_ in range(2):
turtle.forward(600)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(400)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.end_fill()

def draw_cloud(x, y):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x, y)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("white")
turtle.begin_fill()
for \_ in range(6):
turtle.circle(30, extent=180)
turtle.right(120)
turtle.end_fill()

def draw_lawn(x, y):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x + 300, y)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("green")
turtle.begin_fill()
for \_ in range(2):
turtle.forward(600)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(200)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.end_fill()

def draw_road(x, y):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x + 300 , y - 170)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("black")
turtle.begin_fill()
for \_ in range(2):
turtle.forward(600)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(200)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.end_fill()

def draw_road_lines(x, y):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x - 300, y - 270)
turtle.setheading(0)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("white")
turtle.width(5)
for \_ in range(20):
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(10)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.penup()

def draw_pole(x, y):
turtle.goto(x - 8, y - 170)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("black")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.fillcolor("gray")
turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.forward(150)
turtle.setheading(0)
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.setheading(-90)
turtle.forward(150)
turtle.setheading(180)
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.penup()

def draw_box(x, y):
turtle.goto(x, y)
turtle.goto(x + 38, y + 85)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.fillcolor("black")
for \_ in range(2):
turtle.forward(75)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(150)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.penup()

def draw_text(x, y, message):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x, y + 150)
turtle.color("black")
turtle.write(message, align="center", font=("Calibri", 20, "normal"))

def draw_traffic_light(x, y, active_light):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x, y)

    draw_sky(x, y)
    draw_lawn(x, y)
    draw_cloud(150, 180)
    draw_cloud(-50, 330)
    draw_cloud(-250, 180)
    draw_road(x, y)
    draw_road_lines(x, y)
    draw_pole(x, y)
    draw_box(x, y)
    
    turtle.goto(x + 2, y + 75)
    if active_light == "red":
        draw_filled_circle("red", 20)
        draw_text(x, y, "STOP!")
    else:
        draw_filled_circle("gray", 20)
    
    turtle.goto(x + 2, y + 30)
    if active_light == "yellow":
        draw_filled_circle("yellow", 20)
        draw_text(x, y, "Get Ready!!")
    else:
        draw_filled_circle("gray", 20)
    
    turtle.goto(x + 2, y - 15)
    if active_light == "green":
        draw_filled_circle("green", 20)
        draw_text(x, y, "Let's GO !!!")
    else:
        draw_filled_circle("gray", 20)

def simulate_traffic_light():
while True:
turtle.clear()
draw_traffic_light(0, 0, "red")
time.sleep(2)
turtle.clear()
draw_traffic_light(0, 0, "yellow")
time.sleep(2)
turtle.clear()
draw_traffic_light(0, 0, "green")
time.sleep(2)

def close_window():
turtle.bye()

turtle.setup(width=600, height=760)
turtle.title("Traffic Light Simulation \['c' to quit\]")
turtle.bgcolor("grey")
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.onkey(close_window, "c")
turtle.listen()
simulate_traffic_light()
turtle.mainloop()


Please check/fix your indentation and escape characters in the code block.

There's way too much code posted. Can you simplify the example to a [mre] that just demonstrates the problem?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Some issues I see with your code:
At a high level, your traffic lights turn on in the wrong order.  It's not "red -> yellow -> green -> red" but rather "red -> green -> yellow -> red".
To change which light is lit, you redraw the entire scene.  We just need to redraw the traffic lights themselves with a separate turtle.
You're using a while True: which has no place in an event driven world like turtle.  Use turtle's ontimer() method instead.
Below is a rethink of your code with the above changes plus other small tweaks:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_filled_circle(color, radius):
    light.fillcolor(color)
    light.begin_fill()
    light.circle(radius)
    light.end_fill()

def draw_cloud(x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x + 45, y - 30)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color("white")
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(6):
        turtle.circle(30, extent=180)
        turtle.right(120)

    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_lawn():
    width = screen.window_width()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-width/2, 0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color("green")
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(190)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_road():
    width = screen.window_width()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-width/2, -190)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color("black")
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(190)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_road_lines():
    width = screen.window_width()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-width/2, -280)
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color("white")
    turtle.width(5)

    for _ in range(width // 30):
        turtle.forward(20)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(10)
        turtle.pendown()

    turtle.penup()

def draw_pole():
    turtle.goto(-10, -190)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color("black", "gray")
    turtle.setheading(90)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.penup()

def draw_box():
    turtle.goto(37.5, 60)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.fillcolor("black")
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(75)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(150)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()

def draw_text(x, y, message):
    light.penup()
    light.goto(x, y + 150)
    light.color("black")
    light.write(message, align="center", font=("Calibri", 20, "normal"))

def draw_traffic_light():
    light.penup()
    light.goto(0, 15)

    if active_light == "red":
        draw_filled_circle("red", 20)
        draw_text(0, 75, "STOP!")
    else:
        draw_filled_circle("gray", 20)

    light.sety(-30)
    if active_light == "yellow":
        draw_filled_circle("yellow", 20)
        draw_text(0, 75, "Get Ready To Stop!!")
    else:
        draw_filled_circle("gray", 20)

    light.sety(-75)
    if active_light == "green":
        draw_filled_circle("green", 20)
        draw_text(0, 75, "Let's GO !!!")
    else:
        draw_filled_circle("gray", 20)

def simulate_traffic_light():
    global active_light

    light.clear()
    draw_traffic_light()

    if active_light == 'red':
        active_light = 'green'
    elif active_light == 'green':
        active_light = 'yellow'
    elif active_light == 'yellow':
        active_light = 'red'

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(simulate_traffic_light, 2000)  # milliseconds

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=760)
screen.title("Traffic Light Simulation \[click on window to quit\]")
screen.bgcolor("sky blue")
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

draw_lawn()
draw_cloud(150, 180)
draw_cloud(0, 330)
draw_cloud(-150, 180)
draw_road()
draw_road_lines()
draw_pole()
draw_box()

light = Turtle()
light.hideturtle()

active_light = 'red'

simulate_traffic_light()

screen.exitonclick()

